# How to take text entered by user into a variable and combine several variables to create a url

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a very simple application. I have three fields let's say `make`, `model` and `year` that the user enters text into.

How can I combine those three user inputs into one variable and when the user presses `submit` it will create something like this.

```
'http://ford/make/1996/'
```

and then go to that link. I do not want it to open a window just go to that link. Essentially what I'm trying to do is send data via a url to my website once the user fills in the form and presses submit.

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have 3 textboxes, textbox1, textbox2, and textbox3. You can combine them by:

```
var result = textbox1.Text + textbox2.Text + textbox3.Text;
```

Comment: This is what i was asking exactly now i just have to figure out how to make it so it will make a http request with the url that combining this box, when pressing submit. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

On your submit button click handler, try this. Don't forget to put some validation before that.

```
Response.Redirect(string.Format("http://{0}/{1}/{2}", txtMake.Text, txtModel.Text, txtYear.Text));
```

Comment: what's validation. sorry if i sound like an idiot. Im very new to c# im used to working with php.

Comment: Your answer seems like the best. But I cant find anything called submit button click handler. Im using visual studios 2012 and c# Its desktop software app im building..(trying to anyways)

Comment: Does this work with a c# windows application ran on a windows machine?

Comment: This one is for web application. But you can at least use the url building portion and use it when opening browser window from windows app. I will try to provide some sample code for this as soon as i reach home.

Comment: Ok thank you, But I dont want to open the browser window, i just want to load the url that was created, what this will do is send the data that was created to my php script on my server. So the user with the desktop application when pressing "send" it never opens a page for them it just say data sent or something. You know what I mean?

Answer (score 1):

Look at UriBuilder:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdwhd34a.aspx

Sample (there are many ways to use it):

```
UriBuilder myUri = new UriBuilder("http","www.contoso.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

On the button submit run a javascript that combines the values from the textboxes and navigates to the url if this is a website.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Uri class. For example:

```
Uri output = new Uri("http://" + "ford");
output = new Uri(output, "/" + "focus");
output = new Uri(output, "/" + "1995");
```